# Try to fit tasks to machines, Is this a knapsack problem?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have the following problem which I am not sure what type of algorithm I should use. It seems to be a knapsack problem but I've been struggling to get an answer.  Below is the problem description:

Consider a list of n tasks that need to be calculated, each task has requirements on memory, # of cpu cores and network bandwidth:

```
job_num   memory GB   cpu cores,   network GBit  
1            15           1            0.1  
2            1            1            0.1
3            1            2            0.5
4            12           1           0.3
5            1            3            0.1
...
```

Now lets assume we have a large pool of 16GB, 4 core, 1 GB networking machines that we can run these on, but we want to run use as few as possible, how can we do that?

What type of problem is this and any suggestions for solution?

---

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessor_scheduling https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling

Comment: It's best to ask only one question at a time. Those are two completely unrelated problems that you're asking about.

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you for the advise. I have moved the second question to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52430715/which-algorithm-should-i-use-to-fit-as-many-pictures-as-possible-to-a-billboard

Comment: @m69  Thank you for providing the links!