# Which algorithm should I use to fit as many pictures as possible to a billboard?

Tags: algorithm

The problem is like this:

We have a billboard on the highway and it has length-width dimensions (100,150)

We also have a list of advertisement pictures which have dimensions:

```
[
(10,20),
(15,30),
(5, 50),
(80, 100),
....
]
```

How do we calculate the maximum number of ads that can fit on the billboard, and how do we figure out the combination of ads that would fit to give this max number?

What type of problem is this one, and which algorithm should I use?

Comment: We can sort the list of dimensions based on area(length * breadth) . Now, we can just iterate from first to last and see how many you can collect till the area of the billboard is reached. But the problem is, through this method we can't decide on whether the orientation of billboards will fit properly or not .

Comment: It's called a "knapsack" or "bin packing" problem.

Comment: Or more specialized: *rectangle packing*.

Comment: Genetic algorithm + knapsack problem + area of overlapping between ads.